# how do i read file of ints and store in variables in c

Tags: c, file, struct

Ive just started c programming.

I would like to read a file of ints which are in a text file in the format

```
    int1(space)int2(space)int3
    int4(space)int5(space)int6
    int7(space)int8(space)int9

data file example (actually has 25 million lines)

1000002 1 55
1000002 1000006 33
1000002 1000007 8
```

i am trying to read the numbers and each line i would like to store the 3 ints into a separate variable so i can create a struct with 3 ints per struct. I have a function to create the structs however i don't know how to read the numbers in line by line then assign each 3 ints into a temp variable.

I will be using dynamic allocation to store the structs so just array as temp storage

```
    FILE *fp = fopen("uboss.txt", "r");
    //char text[255];
    int i = 1;
    int a = 1;
    int numberArray[9999];
    int tmpUI = 0;
    int tmpAI = 0;
    int tmpPC = 0;

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error Reading File\n");
        exit (0);
    }

   while (!feof(fp))
   {
        fscanf(fp, "%d ", &numberArray[i]);
        printf("Number %d: %d\n",i,numberArray[i]);
        tmpUI = numberArray[a];
        tmpAI = numberArray[a+1];
        tmpPC = numberArray[a+2];
        i++;
   }

    fclose (fp);
```

Comment: `while (!feof(fp))` is not the correct way to check the end of a file. I believe you have to check if the return value of `fscanf` is equal to `EOF`.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you just asking how to scan line by line through the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not the only one asking about this assignment.  Try a simpler approach:

- In a loop, read each line with `fgets()`,
- Then scan the line for 3 integers with `sscanf(str, "%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);` and check the return value, it should be `3`.
- Finally deal with the values: store them, test them, output them...

There might be extra problems to watch for:

- What if the input file contains non numeric values?
- What if the values are larger than can fit in the `int` type.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple if you know how fscanf works (and returns):

```
while( fscanf(fp, "%d%d%d", &tmpUI, &tmpAC, &tmpPC) == 3 )
{
  ...
}
```